# c#.net Word add-in

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I am developing an **add-in** in **C#.net for Office-2013**, that shows a pop up message whenever user **tries to export or share** the document. 
I have seen **word PIA** has the **DocumentBeforeSaveEvent** but no such event for **share and export**.

Thus my query is can I make my own events to be used with the **Word add-in** which shows pop up if user tries to share or export the document.

If yes, what would be the possible step to do so?

The basic purpose of the add-in is to  act as RMS(Right Management System), such that if user tries to save a document that is not protected as per restrict access' templates, then it should automatically attach the default template to the document before user saves it. The object model of Word, is of not much help either, thus would like to know what should be the process to develop such an add-in using **C#.net for Office-2013**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by overwriting the appropriate commands in your Ribbon XML.

You need to add a `<commands>` node to the XML and include subelements for the relevant Word commands as follows:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" 
   onLoad="OnLoad" > 
   <commands> 
     <command idMso="FileSave" onAction="mySave" /> 
   </commands> 
   <ribbon startFromScratch="false"> 
     <tabs> 
       <tab id="tab1" label="Repurpose Command Demo" > 
         <group id="group1" label="Demo Group"> 
           <toggleButton id="togglebutton1"  
             imageMso="AcceptInvitation"  
             size="large"  
             label="Alter Built-ins"  
             onAction="changeRepurpose" /> 
         </group> 
       </tab> 
     </tabs> 
   </ribbon> 
</customUI>
```

You then have to add a corresponding callback that gets executes whenever the user tries to execute the command in question:

```
public void mySave(IRibbonControl control, bool cancelDefault)
{
    If (repurposing)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The Save button has been temporarily repurposed.");
        cancelDefault = False;
    }
    else
    {
        cancelDefault = False;
    }
}
```

MSDN has a full sample here: **[Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb462633%28v=office.12%29.aspx)**

In your case the command ids are probably `FileSaveAsPdfOrXps` and `ShareWithPeople` (or similar). You can find an Excel document containing all Office Ribbon ids here: [idMso Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn833156%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

### Update

After your edit to the original question it looks like you may want to setup an RMS server for Office and define appropriate *Rights Policy Templates*. To get you started you can read up on this topic here: **[Plan Information Rights Management in Office 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179103.aspx?)**

Comment: My query stands in terms of developing an add in using C#.net for office 2013, on how to access the templates using the c#.net code, with which I want to build my add in. The RMS server is already set up, the templates are already deployed, I just want to add the extra functionality by the means of my add in.

The object model of word is of no use too.

Comment: There are pre built templates already deployed, I want to build an add-in using C#.net which would show a prompt message to user whenever he/she tries to share, export etc. the document which are not classified as per the given templates.
I want to write a code and build an add in for the same.

My real query is how to fetch the properties of the templates in restrict access section , or how should my code know if the template is used in the opened document or not.